# how can i solve this problem with Node package manager?

Tags: npm, node-modules, node-webkit

I try to run this install:

```
npm install nw@0.44.1-sdk nw-builder -D
```

But it gives me this problem. if I try to install another package, I don't get this message.

I also clear npm cache and delete node_modules

And I also setup company proxy

> ```
> tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
> npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
> npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! nw@0.44.1-sdk postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the nw@0.44.1-sdk postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\H90431283\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-18T14_48_15_391Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2202#issuecomment-355392727), the problem relies on proxy configuration. You need to properly setup NPM proxy configuration:

```
npm config set proxy http://yourproxyaddress:port
npm config set https-proxy http://yourproxyaddress:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Fully featured discussion is to be found on Github: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2202

Comment: I know, and I did it. Other packages installed correctly like react-router-dom,node-sass,firebase. But this one throw that error :/

Comment: Then something from either your computer either your network provider is blocking `npm` from accessing npmjs repositories. I believe this matter should be forwarded to your sysadmin.